# Is there an inverse of the mongoose model.translateAliases function

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, alias

Is there a way to return an object from model.find() where the fields are mapped to their alias value.

i.e.
schema:

```
const ItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  n: { type: String, required: true, unique: true, alias: 'name' },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Item', ItemSchema);
```

using findOne:

```
Item.findOne()
  .exec(function(err, item){
    console.log(item);
  })
```

returns

```
{
  n: 'nameofitem'
}
```

But I need

```
{
  name: 'nameofitem'
}
```

In my case aggregate project would not work as I am dynamically selecting the model

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: I tried to call `item.toObject({ virtuals: true })` which should return the alias keys according to the documentation (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject), but still it returned the raw document keys.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding [Klemens Zleptnig's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/769726/klemens-zleptnig) comment, you can also set the options at the `mongoose.Schema` level to get translated version of data every time you exec queries.

**Schema**:

```
const { Schema } = require("mongoose").default;

const ItemSchema = new Schema(
  {
    n: {
      alias: "name",
      type: Schema.Types.String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
  },
  {
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
  }
);
```

**Query**:

```js
const escapeRegExp = require("lodash/escapeRegExp");

async function findByName(data) {
  const query = { name: new RegExp(data, "i") };
  return Item.findOne(Item.translateAliases(query)).exec();
}
```